# Maximum likelihood of logit on empirical CDF curve

Tags: binary, estimation, cdf

I have a theoretical decision model of the following type:

\rhat = \r - \rbar = deviations from mean

if \rhat<0:  1/(1+e^((|\rhat|^\delta)/t))

and if \rhat>0: 1-1/(1+e^((|\rhat|^\gamma)/t))

Therefore, the model is an S-shaped curve with an asymmetry about 0 captured by \gamma and \delta. The slope of the curve is determined by t.

I have data for \rhat and would like to fit the above S-curve to the CDF of the data to get estimates of \delta, \gamma, and t. I usually think about this problem as a binary choice problem, but my data is not of that type. It is more along the lines of finding distribution parameters. Should I recover the empirical cdf data for this estimation e.g. using Mathematica's HistogramList command?